# I got some errors for implementation of GeneticAlgo

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to make a time table scheduling program but found some errors. Please watch the following code and solve that error please.

## Errors

These are the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Muhammad Abbas/Downloads/ga02ClassScheduling.py", line 367, in <module>
    population.get_schedules().sort(key=lambda x: x.get_fitness(), reverse=True)
  File "C:/Users/Muhammad Abbas/Downloads/ga02ClassScheduling.py", line 367, in <lambda>
    population.get_schedules().sort(key=lambda x: x.get_fitness(), reverse=True)
  File "C:/Users/Muhammad Abbas/Downloads/ga02ClassScheduling.py", line 84, in get_fitness
    self._fitness = self.calculate_fitness()
  File "C:/Users/Muhammad Abbas/Downloads/ga02ClassScheduling.py", line 106, in calculate_fitness
    if classes[i].get_room().get_seatingCapacity() < classes[i].get_course().get_maxNumbOfStudnets():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_seatingCapacity'
```

### Source Code of the Program

## Variables:

These are the variables which i declare for this program

```
import prettytable as prettytable
import random as rnd
POPULATION_SIZE = 9
NUMB_OF_ELITE_SCHEDULES = 1
TOURNAMENT_SELECTION_SIZE = 3
MUTATION_RATE = 0.1
```

## Data Class

That is the first class which name is DATA

```
class Data:
    ROOMS = [["R1", 25], ["R2", 45], ["R3", 35]]
    MEETING_TIMES = [
        ["MT1", "MWF 09:00 - 10:00"],
        ["MT2", "MWF 10:00 - 11:00"],
        ["MT3", "TTH 09:00 - 10:30"],
        ["MT4", "TTH 10:30 - 12:00"]
                     ]
    INSTRUCTORS = [
        ["T1", "Dr James Web"],
        ["T2", "Mr Mike Brown"],
        ["T3", "Dr Steve Day"],
        ["T4", "Mrs Jane Doe"]
                   ]
    def __init__(self):
        self._rooms = []
        self._meetingTimes = []
        self._instructors = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.ROOMS)):
            self._rooms.append(Room(self.ROOMS[i][0], self.ROOMS[i][1]))
        for i in range(0, len(self.MEETING_TIMES)):
            self._meetingTimes.append(MeetingTime(self.MEETING_TIMES[i][0], self.MEETING_TIMES[i][1]))
        for i in range(0, len(self.INSTRUCTORS)):
            self._instructors.append(Instructor(self.INSTRUCTORS[i][0], self.INSTRUCTORS[i][1]))

        course1 = Course("C1", "325k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1]], 25)
        course2 = Course("C2", "319k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1], self._instructors[2]], 35)
        course3 = Course("C3", "462k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[1]], 25)
        course4 = Course("C4", "464k", [self._instructors[2], self._instructors[3]], 30)
        course5 = Course("C5", "360C", [self._instructors[3]], 35)
        course6 = Course("C6", "303k", [self._instructors[0], self._instructors[2]], 45)
        course7 = Course("C7", "303L", [self._instructors[1], self._instructors[3]], 45)

        self._courses = [course1, course2, course3, course4, course5, course6, course7]

        dept1 = Department("MATH", [course1, course3])
        dept2 = Department("EE", [course2, course4, course5])
        dept3 = Department("PHY", [course6, course7])

        self._depts = [dept1, dept2, dept3]
        self._numberOfClasses = 0

        for i in range(0, len(self._depts)):
            self._numberOfClasses += len(self._depts[i].get_courses())

    def get_rooms(self):
        return self._rooms
    def get_instructors(self):
        return self._instructors
    def get_courses(self):
        return self._courses
    def get_depts(self):
        return self._depts
    def get_meetingTimes(self):
        return self._meetingTimes
    def get_numberOfClasses(self):
        return self._numberOfClasses
```

## Schedule Class

That is the second class which name is Schedule

```
class Schedule:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = data
        self._classes = []
        self._numberOfConflicts = 0
        self._fitness = -1
        self._classNumb = 0
        self._isFitnessChanged = True

    def get_classes(self):
        self._isFitnessChanged = True
        return self._classes

    def get_numberOfConflicts(self):
        return self._numberOfConflicts

    def get_fitness(self):
        if(self._isFitnessChanged == True):
            self._fitness = self.calculate_fitness()
            self._isFitnessChanged = False
        return self._fitness

    def initialize(self):
        depts = self._data.get_depts()
        for i in range(0, len(depts)):
            courses = depts[i].get_courses()    #courses in each departments
            for j in range(0, len(courses)):
                newClass = Class(self._classNumb, depts[i], courses[j])
                self._classNumb += 1
                newClass.set_meetingTime(data.get_meetingTimes()[rnd.randrange(0, len(data.get_meetingTimes()))])
                newClass.set_room(data.get_rooms()[rnd.randrange(0, len(data.get_rooms()))])
                newClass.set_instructor(courses[j].get_instructors()[rnd.randrange(0, len(courses[j].get_instructors()))])
                self._classes.append(newClass)
        return self

    def calculate_fitness(self):
        self._numberOfConflicts = 0
        classes = self.get_classes()
        for i in range(0, len(classes)):

            if classes[i].get_room().get_seatingCapacity() < classes[i].get_course().get_maxNumbOfStudnets():
                self._numberOfConflicts += 1
            for j in range(0, len(classes)):
                if(j >= i):
                    if(classes[i].get_meetingTime() == classes[j].get_meetingTime() and
                       classes[i].get_id() != classes[j].get_id()):
                        if(classes[i].get_room() == classes[j].get_room()):
                            self._numberOfConflicts += 1
                        if(classes[i].get_instructor() == classes[j].get_instructor()):
                            self._numberOfConflicts += 1
        return 1 / ((1.0*self._numberOfConflicts + 1))

    def __str__(self):
        # it returns all the classes of schedule separated by comas
        returnValue = ""
        for i in range(0, len(self._classes)):
            returnValue += str(self._classes[i]) + ", "
        returnValue += str(self._classes[len(self._classes)-1])
        return returnValue
```

## Population Class

Thats the third class which is Population class

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size
        self._data = data
        self._schedules = []
        for i in range(0, size):
            self._schedules.append(Schedule().initialize())
    def get_schedules(self):
        return self._schedules
```

## GeneticAlgorithm Class

Thats the fourth class which is the GeneticAlgorithm class

```
class GeneticAlgorithm:
    def evolve(self, population):
        return self._mutate_population(self._crossover_population(population))

    def _crossover_population(self, pop):
        crossover_pop = Population(0)
        for i in range(NUMB_OF_ELITE_SCHEDULES):
            crossover_pop.get_schedules().append(pop.get_schedules()[i])
        i = NUMB_OF_ELITE_SCHEDULES
        while i < POPULATION_SIZE:
            schedule1 = self._select_tournament_population(pop).get_schedules()[0]
            schedule2 = self._select_tournament_population(pop).get_schedules()[0]
            crossover_pop.get_schedules().append(self._crossover_schedule(schedule1, schedule2))
            i += 1
        return crossover_pop
    def _mutate_population(self, population):
        for i in range(NUMB_OF_ELITE_SCHEDULES, POPULATION_SIZE):
            self._mutate_schedule(population.get_schedules()[i])
        return population

    def _crossover_schedule(self, schedule1, schedule2):
        crossoverSchedule = Schedule().initialize()
        for i in range(0, len(crossoverSchedule.get_classes())):
            if (rnd.random() > 0.5):
                crossoverSchedule.get_classes()[i] = schedule1.get_classes()[i]
            else:
                crossoverSchedule.get_classes()[i] = schedule2.get_classes()[i]
        return crossoverSchedule


    def _mutate_schedule(self,mutateSchedule):
        schedule = Schedule().initialize()
        for i in range(0, len(mutateSchedule.get_classes())):
            if(MUTATION_RATE > rnd.random()):
                mutateSchedule.get_classes()[i] = schedule.get_classes()[i]
        return mutateSchedule

    def _select_tournament_population(self, pop):
        tournament_pop = Population(0)
        i = 0
        while i < TOURNAMENT_SELECTION_SIZE:
            tournament_pop.get_schedules().append(pop.get_schedules()[rnd.randrange(0, POPULATION_SIZE)])
            i += 1
        tournament_pop.get_schedules().sort(key=lambda x:x.get_fitness(), reverse=True)
        return tournament_pop
```

## Course Class

Thats the fifth class which is the Course class

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, number, name, instructors, maxNumbOfStudents):
        self._number = number
        self._name = name
        self._instructors = instructors
        self._maxNumbOfStudents = maxNumbOfStudents
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
    def get_number(self):
        return self._number
    def get_instructors(self):
        return self._instructors
    def get_maxNumbOfStudents(self):
        return self._maxNumbOfStudents
    def __str__(self):
        return self._name
```

## Instructor Class

Thats the sixth class which is Instructor class

```
class Instructor:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self._id = id
        self._name = name
    def get_id(self):
        return self._id
    def get_name(self):
        return self._name
    def __str__(self):
        return self._name
```

## Room Class

Thats the seventh class which is the Room Class

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, number, seatingCapacity):
        self._number = number
        self._seatingCapacity = seatingCapacity
    def get_number(self):
        return self._number
    def get_seatingCapacity(self):
        return self._seatingCapacity
```

## MeetingTime Class

Thats the eighth class which is MeetingTime class

```
class MeetingTime:
    def __init__(self, id, time):
        self._time = time
        self._id = id
    def get_id(self):
        return self._id
    def get_time(self):
        return self._time
```

## Department Class

Thats the ninth class which is the Department class

```
class Department:
    # Batch for my case
    def __init__(self, name, courses):
        self._name = name
        self._courses = courses     # Courses that department offers
    def get_name(self): return self._name
    def get_courses(self): return self._courses
```

## Class class

Thats is the tenth class which name is Class

```
class Class:
    # Course to be scheduled at specific room of department host by an instructor at specific Meeting Time
    def __init__(self, id, dept, course):
        self._id = id
        self._dept = dept
        self._course = course
        self._instructor = None
        self._meetingTime = None
        self._room = None

    def get_id(self):
        return self._id
    def get_dept(self):
        return self._dept
    def get_room(self):
        return self._room
    def get_course(self):
        return self._course
    def get_instructor(self):
        return self._instructor
    def get_meetingTime(self):
        return self._meetingTime

    def set_instructor(self, instructor):
        self._instructor = instructor
    def set_meetingTime(self, meetingTime):
        self._meetingTime = meetingTime
    def set_room(self, room):
        self_room = room

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._dept.get_name()) + "," + str(self._course.get_number()) + "," + \
               str(self._room.get_number()) + "," + str(self._instructor.get_id()) + "," + str(self._meetingTime.get_id())
```

## DisplayMgr Class Plus End Code

Thats the eleventh class which is DisplayMgr Class and the end code of that program.

```
class DisplayMgr:
    def print_available_data(self):
        print("> All Available Data")
        self.print_dept()
        self.print_course()
        self.print_room()
        self.print_instructor()
        self.print_meeting_times()

    def print_dept(self):
        depts = data.get_depts()
        availableDeptsTable = prettytable.PrettyTable(['dept', 'courses'])
        for i in range(0, len(depts)):
            courses = depts.__getitem__(i).get_courses()
            tempStr = "["
            for j in range(0, len(courses) - 1):
                tempStr += courses[j].__str__() + ", "
            tempStr += courses[len(courses) - 1].__str__() + "]"
            availableDeptsTable.add_row([depts.__getitem__(i).get_name(), tempStr])
        print(availableDeptsTable)

    def print_course(self):
        availabelCoursesTable = prettytable.PrettyTable(['id', 'course # ', 'max # of students', 'instructors'])
        courses = data.get_courses()
        for i in range(0, len(courses)):
            instructors = courses[i].get_instructors()
            tempStr = ""
            for j in range(0, len(instructors)-1):
                tempStr += instructors[j].__str__() + ", "
            tempStr += instructors[len(instructors) - 1].__str__()
            availabelCoursesTable.add_row(
                [courses[i].get_number(), courses[i].get_name(), str(courses[i].get_maxNumbOfStudents()), tempStr]
            )
        print(availabelCoursesTable)

    def print_instructor(self):
        availableInstructorsTable = prettytable.PrettyTable(['id', 'instructor'])
        instructors = data.get_instructors()
        for i in range(0, len(instructors)):
            availableInstructorsTable.add_row([instructors[i].get_id(), instructors[i].get_name()])
        print(availableInstructorsTable)

    def print_room(self):
        availableRoomsTable = prettytable.PrettyTable(['room #', 'max seating capacity'])
        rooms = data.get_rooms()
        for i in range(0, len(rooms)):
            availableRoomsTable.add_row([str(rooms[i].get_number()), str(rooms[i].get_seatingCapacity())])
        print(availableRoomsTable)

    def print_meeting_times(self):
        availableMeetingTimeTable = prettytable.PrettyTable(['id', 'Meeting Time'])
        meetingTimes = data.get_meetingTimes()
        for i in range(0, len(meetingTimes)):
            availableMeetingTimeTable.add_row([meetingTimes[i].get_id(), meetingTimes[i].get_time()])
        print(availableMeetingTimeTable)

    def print_generation(self, population):
        table1 = prettytable.PrettyTable(['schedule # ', 'fitness', '# of Conflicts','classes [dept, class, room, instructor'])
        schedules = population.get_schedules()
        for i in range(0, len(schedules)):
            table1.add_row([str(i), round(schedules[i].get_fitness(),3), schedules[i].get_numberOfConflicts(), schedules[i]])
        print(table1)

    def print_schedule_as_table(self, schedule):
        classes = schedule.get_classes()
        table = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Class # ', 'Dept', 'Course (number, max # of students)', 'Room (Capacity', 'Instructor'])
        for i in range(0, len(classes)):
            table.add_row([str(i), classes[i].get_dept().get_name(), classes[i].get_course().get_name() + " (" +
                           classes[i].get_course().get_number() + ", " +
                           str(classes[i].get_course().get_maxNumbOfStudents()) + ")",
                           classes[i].get_room().get_number() + " (" + str(classes[i].get_room().get_seatingCapacity()) +
                           classes[i].get_instructor().get_name() + " (" + str(classes[i].get_instructor().get_id()) +")",
                           classes[i].get_meatingTime().get_time() + " (" + str(classes[i].get_meatingTime().get_id()) +")"
                           ])

        print(table)



data = Data()
displayMgr = DisplayMgr()
displayMgr.print_available_data()
generationNumber = 0
print("\n> Generation # " + str(generationNumber))
population = Population(POPULATION_SIZE)
population.get_schedules().sort(key=lambda x: x.get_fitness(), reverse=True)
displayMgr.print_generation(population)
displayMgr.print_schedule_as_table(population.get_schedules()[0])       # it will print fittest generation of schedule
geneticAlgorithm = GeneticAlgorithm()
while (population.get_schedules()[0].get_fitness() != 1.0):
    generationNumber += 1
    print("\n> Generation # " + str(generationNumber))
    population = geneticAlgorithm.evolve(population)
    population.get_schedules().sort(key=lambda x: x.get_fitness(), reverse=True)
    displayMgr.print_generation(population)
    displayMgr.print_schedule_as_table(population.get_schedules()[0])
print("\n\n")
```

Comment: you set `self.room = None` then you must have some code that never change or sets another value. so when you call `classes[i].get_room().get_seatingCapacity()` Well `get_room()` is `None` so you cant call `get_seatingCapacity()` on `None` as it doesnt have a method called that. You wiull need to go through your code to check why you have not set a room for a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_room(self, room):
    self_room = room
```

you have missing . in set_room(self,room) function . Change it to self._room=room so that it will set the room value and objectType=None will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Look into your the class `DisplayMgr/def` `print_schedule_as_table`
Change `classes[i].get_meatingTime().get_time()` to `meetingTime`